# scrollLeft is not working in firefox

Tags: jquery

I don't know why it's not working in Firefox. Help me to fix this.
I have tried this

```
var clicks = 100;
$('#nextTab').click(function(){$("#mainDivTab").animate({ scrollLeft:clicks }, "300");});
$('#prevTab').click(function(){$("#mainDivTab").animate({ scrollLeft:(-clicks) }, "300");});
```

Comment: No its div element. @Kiran Dash

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ekhdvt0h/ Please check the link here. It works for firefox too.

Comment: Thanks @Kiran Dash. But i found the issue. if mainDivTab element's display property is table-cell, scrollLeft won't work. Thank you very much for your efforts towards my problem.

Comment: Please do write this as an answer.